# Search does not run properly with UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

When I search with following configuration, I can get results but I have several problems :

1. When I search a person, I can see result in output area at the bottom with print command but it does not display on the screen.  If I delete a word, it display result !  For example, if I type Michael, no result appears, but if I delete letter L at the end of Michael word it display result correctly.
2. Sometimes search bar works as first responder , sometimes not. I need to click search twice.
3. If I type a space after a search word, the app crashes with "fatal error: Array index out of range" error.

My code as follows :

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if shouldShowSearchResults {
            return filteredArray.count
        }
        else {
            return homesearchResults.count
        }
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {


    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

    if searchController.searchBar.text?.characters.count > 2

    {

    goSearch(searchController.searchBar.text!)

    }

    let array = (homesearchResults as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)


    filteredArray = array as! [String]



    self.homeTableView.reloadData() }

    func configureSearchController() {

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchController.searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as! UITextField
    textFieldInsideSearchBar.font = UIFont(name: "Bauhaus", size: 19)


   searchController.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "searchicon"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal);


    homeTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar}

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar)  {

    searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()}


func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

    print ("searchBarSearchButton Clicked")

    return true
}


 func goSearch(searchWord: String)

{


    homeSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()


    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://bla.net/home.php")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    let user_id = defaults.integerForKey("dbID") as Int



    let postString = "searchWord=\(searchWord)&userId=\(user_id)";
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in


            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                self.homesearchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.homeimageResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.homeidResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                self.homeTableView.reloadData()

                if let parseJSON = json {

                    print(parseJSON)

                    if let friends  = parseJSON["friends"] as? [AnyObject]
                    {


                        for friendObj in friends
                        {
                            let fullName = (friendObj["name"] as! AnyObject)

                            self.homesearchResults.append(fullName as! String)




                            let friendRequestImage = (friendObj["thumb"] as! AnyObject)

                            self.homeimageResults.append(friendRequestImage as! String)


                            let NotID = (friendObj["id"] as! AnyObject)

                            self.homeidResults.append(NotID as! String)


                        }


                        self.homeTableView.reloadData()

                    } else if(parseJSON["message"] != nil)
                    {

                        let errorMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String
                        if(errorMessage != nil)
                        {
                            self.displayAlertMessage(errorMessage!)
                        }
                    }
                }}
            catch {
                print("json error: \(error)")
            }

    }



    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to wrap your do/catch statement in a dispatch_async call (in your doSearch method):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
     do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,
    ....
})
```